# Accessing a property of a sibling project dependency

Tags: maven-2, maven

Let's say I have

```
<properties>
...
    <module.deployPath>/admin</module.deployPath>
...
</properties>
```

in the pom.xml of the project **A**.

And now I'd like to access ${module.deployPath} in another project **B** where project **A** is listed as dependency of project **B**.

Is this possible somehow without using external property files or settings.xml?

Thank you for your help!

Cheers,

b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying strictly within Maven's property access mechanism, I'm almost certain you can't do that. If you were to add the [GMaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code) and write some Groovy code, then it would probably be possible to get and parse the dependency's pom to get at the property you're looking for.