# Maven - access properties file from dependency

Tags: java, maven

Expanding upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681635/accessing-a-property-of-a-sibling-project-dependency), if using a properties file in the dependency is the original question possible?

Answer (score 3):

Usually you would do the following:

1. Create a pom-packaged project, using it as a parent pom
2. in this parent pom, read the property files you want to read using the [Maven properties plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) by binding it's [read-project-properties goal](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html) to the validate phase.
3. Refer to this parent pom in all the poms that shall share the properties read.